# extrude shape from sphere

Tags: modeling

I wanted model a robot for nothing else than improving my blender skills. I've started with an image I found online but have hit a hurdle early on. I started with a sphere to get the main head shape but have not found a good way to extrude the detail shown by the red arrows. 
[image]

Apart from extruding I also tried modelling the detail as a separate piece of geo with snapping to faces turned on. I almost got what I wanted but the results were not great - I am sure there is a simpler way.

What would you recommend ?

Thanks
rob

Comment: Could you please tell me why Snap to Face isn't working for you very well? Could you post example of it? I'm doing it this way and everything works ok.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to make a mesh that from the front has the profile you want, but is a prism/cylinder with flat ends; then do a boolean intersect with a sphere of slightly larger radius.  Then you can union that with the rest of the robot head.

Once you are confident you will not longer have to adjust the geometry of any of the elements of the boolean you can apply the modifiers to create a final mesh.  or not.

Also, you probably want to use a UVsphere with the poles on the sides where the ears are.

[image: the various stages of the workflow]

If the fact that the sides of the "face" are coplanar to the YZ plane is a problem, an alternate technique would be to discard all but the outer face polygon and then extrude/scale relative to the origin to give it conical sides.  (this way the rim polygons would be perpendicular to the sphere's surface instead of perpendicular to the X axis).